# Dynamically creating custom layouts programmatically exactly like static xmls in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I am using this HorizontalScrollView here - http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 and basically created three horizontal levels as shown in using xml statically.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineartoc1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tocheader"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="150px"
            android:text="example"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <a.b.c.d.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tocheader"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="150dip"
            android:text="example"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <a.b.c.d.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tocheader"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="150dip"
            android:text="example"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <a.b.c.d.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!--
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title4"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#88000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="example"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <a.b.c.d.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am creating three horizontal list views with text on top of each and now these are placed one below the other relatively. How it works is initally only the first list has some items. Clicking on one item in the first horizontal list view creates the next horizontal list and so on for the next level. But since it is created in the xml I can only have a fixed number of levels - three in my case. How do I do the exact same thing with the same positions programmatically so I can have 'n' level support. Also the whole thing is wrapped in scrollview so the page never ends and there is place for n levels.

Comment: you should use `android-listview` tag instead of `listview`... since `listview` can apply to many things (such as the .NET `listview`) :)

Comment: Well actually I did not want to put it in the first place because my code does not involve the android listview but a custom horizontal list view so went with generic one instead, but I see your point :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a handle to your LinearLayout in code by using findViewById(), and then call .addView(View child, LayoutParams) and set up your child views that way.

Remember to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams.* when you're setting up views inside your LinearLayout.